# Run DLL only in debug mode

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, aleagpu

I'm working on AI SDK but I use Alea GPU dlls.

My problem is that Alea has a bug in release mode which I think is because of some compiler condition. **So... is any chance or way to run included dll only in debug mode and rest of the app in release mode?**

thanks

Comment: Possibly.  Check the configuration manager screen.  you can specify for a release build, which components are built in release mode and which are built in debug mode.   you might have to reference the Alea DLLs in a unique project that you only build in debug mode.

Comment: have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788605/if-debug-vs-conditionaldebug

Comment: The app doesn't run in "debug mode" or "release mode", the compiler compiles it in "debug mode" or "release mode" which is a compiler option, not an execution context. You can include the "debug mode" DLL for that part with release mode for everything else. Unless the bug is that the debugger needs to be attached for it to operate properly...

Comment: @RonBeyer thanks your solution is so simple...

Comment: But included DLL is already compiled and you can't switch mode. You only can switch mode for your own code. Probably there is problem with code optimization in release mode, try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/38633044/3975391