# Clear stack variable memory

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management

I have 8 uints which represent a security key like this:

```
uint firstParam = ...;
uint secondParam = ...;
uint thirdParam = ...;
uint etcParam = ...;
uint etcParam = ...;
```

They are allocated as local variables, inside of an UNSAFE method.
Those keys are very sensitive.
I was wondering do those locals on the stack get deleted when the method is over? Does the UNSAFE method have an affect on this? MSDN says that Unsafe code is automatically pinned in memory.

If they are not removed from memory, will assigning them all to 0 help at the end of the method, even though analyzers will say this has no effect?

So I tested zeroing out the variables. However, in x64 Release mode the zeroing is removed from the final product (checked using ILSpy)
Is there any way to stop this?

Here is the sample code (in x64 Release)

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int num = new Random().Next(10, 100);
    Console.WriteLine(num);
    MethodThatDoesSomething(num);
    num = 0;                         // This line is removed!
    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static void MethodThatDoesSomething(int num)
{
    Console.WriteLine(num);
}
```

The num = 0 statement is removed in x64 release.

I cannot use SecureString because I'm P/Invoking into a native method which takes the UInts as a paramter.

I'm P/Invoking into the unmanaged method AllocateAndInitializeSid, which takes 8 uints as parameters. What could I do in this scenerio?

I have tried adding

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining | MethodImplOptions.NoOptimization)]
```

to the sample code (above Main method), however, the num = 0 is STILL removed!

Comment: Please read [Should “Edit:” in edits be discouraged?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255644/215552) while the answers were mixed, most of the voting was for the answer "Yes", it should be discouraged. Stack Overflow is more of a knowledge base, where questions serve as inspiration for answers to practical programming problems. When someone comes to the question a year from now, they may have a hard time understanding the question with all of the EDIT N markers everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**: after some reasoning I've come to correct this answer.

DO NOT use `SecureString`, as @Servy and @Alejandro point out in the comments, it is not considered really secure anymore and will give a misguided sense of security, probably leading to futhering unconsidered exposures.

I have <strike>striked</strike> the passages I'm not comfortable with anymore and, in their place, would recommend as follows.

To assign `firstParam` use:

```cs
firstParam = value ^ OBFUSCATION_MASK;
```

To read `firstParam` use (again):

```cs
firstParam ^ OBFUSCATION_MASK;
```

The `^` (bitwise XOR) operator is the inverse of itself, so applying it twice returns the original value. By reducing the **time** the value exists without obfuscation (for the CPU time is actually the number of machine code cycles), its exposure is also reduced. When the value is stored for long-term (say, 2-3 microseconds) it should always be obfuscated. For example:

```cs
private static uint firstParam; // use static so that the compiler cannot remove apparently "useless" assignments

public void f()
{
    // somehow acquire the value (network? encrypted file? user input?)
    firstParam = externalSourceFunctionNotInMyCode() ^ OBFUSCATION_MASK; // obfuscate immediately
}
```

Then, several microseconds later:

```cs
public void g()
{
    // use the value
    externalUsageFunctionNotInMyCode(firstParam ^ OBFUSCATION_MASK);
}
```

The two `external[Source|Usage]FunctionNotInMyCode()` are entry and exit points of the value. The important thing is that as long as the value is stored in *my code* it is never in the plain, it's always obfuscated. What happens before and after *my code* is not under our control and we must live with it. At some point values must enter and/or exit. Otherwise what program would that be?

One last note is about the `OBFUSCATION_MASK`. I would randomize it for every start of the application, but ensure that the entropy is high enough, that means that the count of `0` and `1` is maybe not fifty/fifty, but near it. I think [RNGCryptoServiceProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider?view=netcore-3.1) will suffice. If not, it's always possible to count the bits or compute the entropy:

```cs
private static readonly uint OBFUSCATION_MASK = cryptographicallyStrongRandomizer();
```

At that point it's relatively difficult to identify the sensitive values in the binary soup and maybe even irrelevant if the data was paged out to disk.

As always, security must be balanced with cost and efficiency (in this case, also readability and maintainability).

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

Even with pinned unmanaged memory you cannot be sure if the physical memory is paged out to the disk by the OS.

In fact, in nations where Internet Bars are very common, clients may use your program on a publicly accessible machine. An attacker may try and do as follows:

1. compromise a machine by running a process that occasionally allocates all the RAM available;
2. wait for other clients to use that machine and run a program with sensitive data (such as username and password);
3. once the rogue program exhausts all RAM, the OS will page out the virtual memory pages to disk;
4. after several hours of usage by other clients the attacker comes back to the machine to copy unused sectors and slack space to an external device;
5. his hope is that `pagefile.sys` changed sectors several times (this occurs through sector rotation and such, which **may** not be avoided by the OS and can depend on hardware/firmware/drivers);
6. he brings the external device to his dungeon and slowly but patiently analyze the gathered data, which is mainly binary gibberish, but may have slews of ASCII characters.

By analyzing the data with all the time in the world and no pressure at all, he may find those sectors to which `pagefile.sys` has been written several "writes" before. There, the content of the RAM and thus heap/stack of programs can be inspected.

If a program stored sensitive data in a `string`, this procedure would expose it.

Now, you're using `uint` not `string`, but the same principles still apply. To be sure to not expose any sensitive data, even if paged out to disk, you can use secure versions of types, <strike>such as `SecureString`</strike>.

The usage of `uint` somewhat protects you from ASCII scanning, but to be really sure you should never store sensitive data in unsafe variables, <strike>which means you should somehow convert the `uint` into a `string` representation and store it exclusively in a `SecureString`</strike>.

Hope that helps someone implementing secure apps.

Comment: I'm P/Invoking into the unmanaged method AllocateAndInitializeSid, which takes 8 UInts as parameters. What could I do about this?

Comment: Sorry I can't help you much, but take a look at this link, it's about preventing memory paging: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/secure-programming-cookbook/0596003943/ch13s03.html

Comment: I will look into it. Thank you

Comment: I would also take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1166952/net-secure-memory-structures

Comment: Ok, I will look into it. Thanks

Comment: And even stuff like secure string doesn't eliminate the problem, it just shrinks the window in which you're vulnerable from the lifetime of the variable to *just* the place where it's constructed and uses of it that cannot be encrypted.

Comment: Note that even [Microsoft recommends dropping `SecureString`](https://github.com/dotnet/platform-compat/blob/master/docs/DE0001.md), it only reduces the chance of leakage (don't eliminates it). Moreover, in .NET Core it's completely broken to the point that it just stores a plain string, and Microsoft refuses to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

In .NET, you can never be sure that variables are actually cleared from memory.

Since the CLR manages the memory, it's free to move them around, liberally leaving old copies behind, including if you purposely overwrite them with zeroes o other random values. A memory analyzer or a debugger may still be able to get them if it has enough privileges.

So what can you do about it?

Just terminating the method leaves the data behind in the stack, and they'll be eventually overwritten by something else, without any certainity of when (or if) it'll happen.

Manually overwriting it will help, provided the compiler doesn't optimize out the "useless" assignment (see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38632939/2557263) for details). This will be more likely to success if the variables are short-lived (before the GC had the chance to move them around), but you still have NO guarrantes that there won't be other copies in other places.

The next best thing you can do is to terminate the whole process immediately, preferably after overwritting them too. This way the memory returns to the OS, and it'll clear it before giving it away to another process. You're still at the mercy of kernel-mode analyzers, though, but now you've raised the bar significantly.